# Подключение библиотеки Python без установки

Tags: python

Появилась необходимость подключить библиотеку, ну возможности ее поставить нет. На сервере я не root, и при попытке поставить библиотеку дает ошибку типа не хватает прав на запись. Для полного моего счастья мне нужна библиотека requests, можно ли ее как-нибудь подключить не устанавливая?

Comment: Она, вроде, представляет из себя .py-файл, который можно просто положить в каталог к вашему проекту.

Comment: А можно по подробнее по поводу этого дела? Я просто новичок в питоне, не совсем догоняю, как это реализовать..

Comment: Берете requests.py и кладете этот файл в каталог с вашим проектом.

Comment: Из сорцов ``python setup.py install --user`` или ``pip install --user Pillow``

Comment: @uralbash: не нужно `setup.py install` использовать напрямую (нет опции uninstall). Лучше использовать `pip install` (есть uninstall, кэширование и куча другой функциональности).

Comment: @jfs: ставится в окружение, можно пипом удалить

Comment: @uralbash: `setup.py install` не предоставляет достаточно информации в общем случае, чтобы чисто всё удалить. Следует использовать `pip` для установки. Никогда не советуйте `setup.py install` вместо `pip install`, крому специальных случаев.

Comment: @jfs: в чём разница? Самописные модули или те которые в разработке через пип не удобно ставить.

Comment: @uralbash: чушь. Если `setup.py install` работает, то и `pip install` работает в большинстве случаев. Если Вы не знаете как эмулировать `setup.py develop` (для модулей *"в разработке"*) с помощью pip, то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для установки Питон пакетов можно обойтись без root. Например, можно создать [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html) в доступной для записи директории или устанавливать в пользовательскую директорию:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user requests
```

Если в данный момент нет интернета или другого способа получить дистрибутив `requests`, то можно попробовать использовать копию `requests`, которая включена в установку `pip`, которая поставляется с недавними версиями Питона:

```
$ python3 -c "from pip._vendor import requests"
```

> В моем случае python 2.7.3, проверял на 3 все работает, а вот на втором не очень..

Если вы не можете до 2.7.9+ обновится, где `pip` поставляется с `python`, то `pip` и `virtualenv` могут быть и так доступны отдельно в системе (попробуйте `pip`, `virtualenv` команды напрямую). Если они не доступны, то достаточно [скачать `virtualenv.py` и запустить его: `python virtualenv.py имя`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598559/4279). В активированном virtualenv, уже можно `pip install requests` запустить.

Comment: В моем случае python 2.7.3, проверял на 3 все работает, а вот на втором не очень..

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, использовать [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) -- это совет номер один. Но если по-какой нибудь причине этот способ не катит (некоторые хостинг провайдеры, к примеру, не дают такой возможности), тогда можно поступить следующим образом:

1. установить библиотеку requests на свой домашний компьютер (тут опять рекомендую делать это в виртуальную среду virtuaenv)
2. Найти в папке с пакетами (должна называться `site-packages' -- ищите внутри виртуального окружения, если использовали его) папку библиотеки requests
3. Создать папку для пакетов на компьютере, на котором будет запускаться скрипт (Пусть для примера это будет /home/username/python-library). Скопировать туда папку requests.
4. В скрипте, который будете запускать, пропишите где-то вначале:
   `import sys
   sys.path.append(/home/username/python-library)`
   Теперь можете скрипт спокойно запускать - он будет искать импортируемые библиотеки в заданной папке. 
   Если это не скрипт в одиночном файле, а пакет, то сделать это надо в файле `__main__`